# How to count words that only have letters and no numbers in a textarea using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string with letters, numbers and spaces. I want to count words that only have letters and ignoring numbers.

For example, I have this string:

```
72634672 2374723654 2423 623623643 7474.747bbberb 7347547345 uhfuherhfru uruhreuhre
```

In this textarea:

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="detect">DETECT</button>
```

So, I do this:

```
$("#detect").click(function(){
   var text = $("#text").val();
   var text2 = text.replace(/\d+/g, ''); //removing numbers

   var words = $.trim(text2).split(" "); //count words
   alert("String: "+text2+" Number of words: " +words.length);
});
```

The problem is the result shows me this:

```
String:     .bbberb  uhfuherhfru uruhreuhre || Number of words: 4
```

But there are 3 words in that result, so I would like to get this:

```
String: .bbberb  uhfuherhfru uruhreuhre || Number of words: 3
```

How can I fix it? 
I'd like your help.

Comment: "I want to count words that only have letters and ignoring numbers."  Then why are you removing numbers from words?  From your example string, only two words are alpha only

Answer (score 1):

`split` accepts regular expressions.

You can treat multiple spaces as one space like this:

```
$.trim(text2).split(/ +/);
```

That will ignore the extra spaces that are left after removing the numbers.

Comment: I would probably go further, and use `.split(/\s+/)` to split on _all_ whitespace.

Comment: @StephenP makes a good point, in case the string may contain tabs or newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the empty entries:

```
 var text2 = text.replace(/\d+/g, ''); //removing numbers
 var words = $.trim(text2).split(" ").filter(a => a != ""); //count words

 console.log("String: "+text2+" Number of words: " +words.length);
```